# LR merc_timer_handle_t

Tags: c, sockets, automated-tests

I want to use `"merc_timer_handle_t"` to record time in loadrunner, but when I create a scenario, LR gives an error message:`"Syntax error on line 15 near "MasterT""`.

I'd like to know how to use `"merc_timer_handle_t"`, here is my script

```
#define _EOF '#'
#include "lrs.h"
#include "web_api.h"

Action ()
{
    char *recvbuf;
    int recvlen=0;
    int rc;
    double trans_time;

    int i, baseIter = 1000; 
    char dude[1000]; 
    double wasteTime, actualElapsedTime; 
    merc_timer_handle_t MasterT, timer;
    int n = 100;


    rc = lrs_create_socket("socket0", "TCP", "LocalHost=0", "RemoteHost=192.168.1.130:10001", LrsLastArg);  

    if (rc = 0 ) 
    {
        lr_end_transaction("Conn_socket", LR_PASS);

        return 0;
    }
    else 
    {

    }

        //Start transaction 
    lr_start_transaction("Conn_socket");

    // Examine the total elapsed time of the action 

    MasterT = lr_start_timer(); 

    // Create some elapsed time for the transaction 
    for (i=0; i< 100; ++i) 

            sprintf(dude, 

                "This is the way we create elapsed time artificially = %d", i); 


    // Create some wasted time and record it with timer 
    timer = lr_start_timer(); 

    for (i=0; i< 100; ++i) 

            sprintf(dude, 

                "This is the way we waste time in a script = %d", i); 

    wasteTime = lr_end_timer(timer); 

    lr_output_message("User created waste time = %lf", wasteTime); 

    lr_output_message("Before lr_waste_time: Duration = %lf - Waste = %lf",         

    lr_get_transaction_duration("Conn_socket"), 

    lr_get_transaction_wasted_time("Conn_socket")); 

    /* Convert Timer in seconds to wasted time in milliseconds 

     and add to internally generated waste time */ 

    wasteTime *= 1000; 

    lr_wasted_time(wasteTime); 

    lr_output_message("After lr_waste_time: Duration = %lf - Waste = %lf", 

    lr_get_transaction_duration("Conn_socket"), 

    lr_get_transaction_wasted_time("Conn_socket")); 

    lr_output_message("Think time = %lf",lr_get_transaction_think_time("Conn_socket")); 


    lrs_send("socket0","buf0", LrsLastArg);

    lrs_receive ("socket0","buf1",LrsLastArg);

    lrs_get_last_received_buffer ("socket0",&recvbuf,&recvlen);

    lrs_send("socket0", "buf2", LrsLastArg);

    lrs_receive("socket0", "buf3", LrsLastArg);

    lrs_send("socket0", "buf4", LrsLastArg);

    lrs_receive("socket0", "buf5", LrsLastArg);

    lrs_send("socket0", "buf6", LrsLastArg);

    lrs_receive("socket0", "buf7", LrsLastArg);

    lrs_send("socket0", "buf8", LrsLastArg);

    lrs_receive("socket0", "buf9", LrsLastArg);


    lr_end_transaction("Conn_socket",LR_AUTO); 

    actualElapsedTime = lr_end_timer(MasterT); 

    lr_output_message("Total Elapsed time for Action = %lf", actualElapsedTime);     

    lrs_close_socket("socket0");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lr_set_transaction(
     "foo"
     lr_get_transaction_duration("blahwoof")
          -lr_get_transaction_wasted_time("blahwoof")
          -lr_get_transaction_think_time("blahoof"),
     lr_get_transaction_status("blahwoof")
   ;
```

Or, after you run the test just run a query against the [Event_Meter] table, joined to the [Event_Map] table for your transaction names.   The wasted time and the think time are tracked for every recorded event in the event meter table